# Can ailerons be used to control yaw and pitch

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, ailerons, vtol

Is it possible for an aileron to be used to control the roll, pitch and yaw of a vtol drone

Comment: You say "VTOL" drone, I assume you want the ailerons to control y/p/r when in forward flight? I don't see the ailerons having any effect at low speeds during VTOL transition.

Comment: Should not you confuse the reader with your vtol. You should only say airplane as too many type of drone, from an airplane-like to a helicopter-like.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the geometry of the vehicle, up to a degree yes. However, with a classic aileron setup and no rudder, it might be impossible to control roll and yaw independently. A split flap (up and down on same wing) would be required to more effectively control yaw, as that can in theory generate drag on one side without much affecting lift. The B2 bomber sports a similar configuration.

Comment: I once built a model glider with a little dihedral. With coordinated aileron and rudder input it would turn nicely, but when only the ailerons were deflected, the adverse yaw made it yaw without any tendency to roll. Due to the lack of bank it would continue on the same course, but now with considerable sideslip.

Comment: @PeterKämpf That’s interesting! The asymmetric lift due sideslip must have cancelled out with asymmetric lift from aileron deflection. Coincidence or design?

Comment: Pure coincidence!

Comment: Yes sir, we can see the dihedral stability (to roll) was stronger than than aileron tendency to create roll. My guess it was also a high wing.  So much is learned from these little models.

Comment: Yes, and rolling back into low aileron from "dihedral effect" from side slip (as I learned from you).

Comment: @PeterKämpf Nice. A little unfortunate for that glider, but great experience to make first hand! Have edited my answer to not categorically rule out yaw control with normal ailerons only (although in your example you still needed the rudder for independent roll and yaw control).

Comment: I would straighten it up with rudder to see difference in side slip roll and dihedral stability counterforces.  Let's not forget rolling contribution of tail.  Have noticed the 1 meter carbon composite "Elf" glider has about 2/3 up, 1/3 down.  I hope to fly it next to my own designs.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni: You guessed correctly, even though the fuselage was rather small - this was not a scale glider. And with coordinated rudder it flew very nicely.